# Corrupt Application.Current.Properties in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

If you write an unrecognized datatype [such as a C# DateTimeOffset] to Application.Current.Properties, it appears to corrupt the dictionary [ie the dictionary cannot deserialize]

But how do you fix it?

Application.Current.Properties.Clear() crashes because .Clear() first tries to deserialize? So you can't just "start over" with a clean dictionary.

I assume there is a file SOMEWHERE [just building a UWP app at the moment] I could delete but darned if I can find it.

Answer (score 2):

The settings are stored in a file named [PropertyStore.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/WindowsSerializer.cs).  On UWP it should be stored in ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder

Comment: Perfect! Worked well.

Comment: You should [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it's the correct one.